# What is the best why to Activate or Lock a user on MVC 5 Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a good way to Activate a user (after validating the email for example) or just implement it as a property in ApplicationUser and then do the rest of checking and validating manual?

Comment: This is a helpful blog post http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.ae/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this helpful blog regarding this.
it's a manual process but this worked for me.
http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.ae/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html